# texmacs does not interpret commands

Tags: texmacs

I started to use Texmacs. But the output contains non interpreted commands like the following. For

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

the output is

[image: broken output]

I tried both: export to pdf and ps. Should be an easy question, but I didn't get to read the user manual so far.

edit: 
Minimum working example. This is the original code. It compiles fine, if I do not use texmacs.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno]{article} %11 pt
\begin{document}
blabla
\thispagestyle{empty}
blabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Stephen -- It's been many years since I tried TeXmacs, but I don't see how you could include a MWE for a 'what you see is what you want' program..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding about TeXmacs. To the contrary of LyX, TeXmacs is NOT an interface to (La)TeX, but a WYSIWYG program with an engine of its own, distinct from any engine of the TeX family. It uses TeX fonts though, and can import and export LaTeX files.

Comment: Interesting. First, I do not think that this is what I want. I was looking for an convenient editor. Second, the editor should work on tex files for collaboration, which is not the case with LyX (a nice tool except for that).

Comment: @Chris TeXmacs is not an editor for TeX/LaTeX; you probably want a multiplatform editor such as TeXworks or TeXStudio.

Comment: I wouldn't call LyX an interface to LaTeX, either.